# Why can't I pass an enum as argument without referencing the assembly that contains it?

Tags: c#

So let's say I have this enum in assembly A:

```
// In assembly A
public enum MyEnum { MyValueA = 1, MyValueB = 2 }
```

And this method on assembly B (assembly B has assembly A as reference)

```
// In Assembly B
public void DoSomething(MyEnum value)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

If I know the value and I'm coding assembly C that references assembly B, is there a reason why I can't do this? Is there a way to do it?

```
// In assembly C
DoSomething(1);
```

**I know this is not a good practice.**

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Mostly I want to know why I can't. I'm aware there are 100 ways, but I want to know one without touching assembly A and not adding references to anything.

Comment: You would need to reference assembly A since assembly C doesn't know about the enum.

Comment: @Botonomous yes, I know that. But enums are stored and passed as integers. I want to know why this behaviour is not accepted ;)

Comment: Even though they are integers at value level, they are still their own type and live in a separate namespace.

Comment: The type system is designed to help you *avoid* making mistakes. You apparently "know" that `1` is a possible representation of a valid member of the enum - but why not let the compiler *verify* that assertion rather than letting you potentially make an error?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hello again and thanks for helping me like 4 years ago (you don't remember I do). So the only reason you can't do this is because the compiler protects you against mistakes?

Comment: The enum can be represented by an int, we get that.  The actual "choices" of an enum though are ***defined*** by assembly A, if assembly C needs the enum, how would it know what are valid values if not referencing assembly A?  your enum is not a known type to the framework, so how could C possibly know about it without a reference?

Comment: @Kritner Valid values, that was the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kritner if you want to, you can post it as the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum can be represented by an int, we get that. The actual "choices" of an enum though are defined by assembly A, if assembly C needs the enum, how would it know what are valid values if not referencing assembly A? your enum is not a known type to the framework, so how could C possibly know about it without a reference?

You either need to have a reference to assembly A from C, or perhaps make another assembly that could contain the enum, and be referenced by both A and C.

Answer (score 0):

You could take int as an argument instead of the Enum. The value passed by the enum from Assembly A should be correct then, but Assembly B would compile, because it would not need to know about MyEnum type

Comment: I fully agree. However, that will break existing calls in assembly B, and if you really want to you could overload the method in assembly A. But what if I don't want to change both? (I only have access to assembly C)

Comment: Also this defeats the purpose of using an enum.

Comment: @Botonomous I'm not the one who decided it should be this way ;). If it were up to me I'd add the reference and boom there you go.